# Ignore gridview cells containing dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a grid view with controls in it.
Grid view has css class "grid".

I am looping over grid view and selecting text in it, but I dont want to select text inside the dropdowns which are in this grid view.

```
$('.grid tr td').live('mouseover',
        function () {
                $(this).attr("title", $(this).text());
                $(this).aToolTip({
                    // no need to change/override  
                    closeTipBtn: 'aToolTipCloseBtn',
                    toolTipId: 'aToolTip',
                    // ok to override  
                    fixed: false,                   // Set true to activate fixed position  
                    clickIt: false,                 // set to true for click activated tooltip  
                    inSpeed: 200,                   // Speed tooltip fades in  
                    outSpeed: 100,                  // Speed tooltip fades out  
                    tipContent: '',                 // Pass in content or it will use objects 'title' attribute  
                    toolTipClass: 'defaultTheme',   // Set class name for custom theme/styles  
                    xOffset: 5,                     // x position  
                    yOffset: 5,                     // y position  
                    onShow: null,                   // callback function that fires after atooltip has shown  
                    onHide: null                    // callback function that fires after atooltip has faded out  
                });


        });
```

This is my jquery code to loop through grid, but I dont know how to filter dropdowns from this loop.

I tried `$('.grid tr td').not('.dropdownCssClass').live('mouseover',`
but not working
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the following selector:

```
$('.grid tr td:not(:has(select))')
```

or

```
$('.grid tr td:not(:has(.dropdownCssClass))')
```